# html & javascript to change URL on a form action based on a drop down

Tags: javascript, form, html, url

Using simple html and javascript how can I have one html form that asks two questions:

- Text OppID
- Dropdown LegalEntity

LegalEntity will have available company1 & company2

When company1 is selected the URL executed is `xxx.company1.com?ToppID=(the value of OppID text field)`

When company2 is selected the URL executed is `xxx.company2.com?ToppID=(the value of OppID text field)`

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a table. I hope you understand what i'm trying to say. Sorry for my english.

below is a form in a table with dropdown.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table class="dropDownList" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="dropDownOptions" id="feedback_dropdown" style="width:150px;">
                        <option value="Option2">Company1</option>
                        <option value="Option1">Company2</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

<script>
        var el_option = document.getElementById("dropDownList");
        el_option.addEventListener("change", function() {


                if (this.selectedIndex == 1){
                    //event change link 
                } else {
                    //event change link 
                }

        }, false);

</script>
</html>
```